# Class B with same fields as Class A

Tags: typescript, oop

I'm still looking for a clean way to declare a second class having the same fields as the first one.
I guess this is not possible, as I saw at compile time, we cannot have class fields. Even at runtime, having fields with `Object.keys` is only possible after initialization. (would return values which are defined).

Case:

```
class Entity {
  public id!: string;

  public uuid!: string;

  public firstname!: string;

  public lastname!: string;
}
```

Now I want to add `weights` (probably with minor refactoring on client code).

Logically, I either need to declare `weights` on the same class, if possible, or in a second twin class like:

```
class EntityWeights {
  public id!: number;

  public uuid!: number;

  public firstname!: number;

  public lastname!: number;
}
```

Then I would keep an eye on both classes to have a consistent code (not optimal).

If I change only `Entity` to add weights, I would do:

```
class Entity {
  public id!: [string, number];

  public uuid!: [string, number];

  public firstname!: [string, number];

  public lastname!: [string, number];
}
```

I tried this, turned out on client code, where I'm passing `const entity = new Entity({___})` to other code like `putInDB(entity)`, I cannot refactor that to only have either weights, or values.

How would you do ?

Comment: Do these *have* to be classes? If they are simple DTOs, then you can just have them as interfaces and then `EntityWeights` will be a mappted type: `type EntityWeights = {[P in keyof Entity]: number}`

Comment: It is a prior work, used everywhere in tests too, probably true but would be hard to refacto now. good point solution though

Comment: Actually, without changing to interface, it works as expected !! with optional VS required included !! this is just great, make as a solution please.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `implements` to constrain `EntityWeights` to have *every property* of `Entity` with `Record<keyof Entity, unknown>`. Every property is mandatory while you can choose their type freely.

```
class EntityWeights implements Record<keyof Entity, unknown> {
  public id!: number;
  public uuid!: number;
  public firstname!: number;
  public lastname!: number;
}
```

There will be an error when you are missing properties:

```
class EntityWeights2 implements Record<keyof Entity, unknown> {
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: Type 'EntityWeights2' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<keyof Entity, unknown>': firstname, lastname(2420)
  public id!: number;
  public uuid!: number;
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiB2AXAlogntA3gWAFDWgAcBXAIxGWGmQBMBCALmgkQCdl4BzAbjwJPKVoxYrUbM2HHnyJkKVAGbJWLeGAC2AU3Et2XXvlmCq4VRu1NdUgwF88eUJBgIU6AOqbknABaIYydUIQTS0kGAAlTWAAe1YaAB4Aa000aIU4JFQ0ABpheET4aIB3eAA+LBkBeWp6JnhidVJNVgN+OSERMTqGppbK9sVlMy1xesbm1qNq00Q1Ee7xvtw7XHtcRygM1zQPL18IACZqQODQv2hImLiklLStrNzifMKS8pxcAHoPggIAPX+AYDAXBWKxYkwACpoQiaaAAchcWV2Pj8Bzh1Bg6mQUCk0EQ3lhCmiIBAxVxhDBMNYKE0MAUYPUeOhsLhl1iCWSqXSiPQj2exTKcKYShUs3MuRmc00AAoDgAWA4ABgAlP1jDVRj0Jmrqp1atAxr1bEA)

Comment: Exactly what I need, Compiler is now aware..

Comment: Except for required VS optional, It looks like compiler wants all fields to be required on subclass. Not a big problem though

Comment: In that case, use a mapped type. See here: https://tsplay.dev/wXqbVN